# Scrollview moves focused editText out of view when its numeric right aligned

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview

I put five editText in a linearLayout in a horizontalScrollview.

When the editText is right aligned and has number as inputtype, the scrollview scrolls completely to the right when the editText got focus, even if that means for the edittext to go out of the view

I did different tests and it seems to only happens when the edit text is right aligned AND input type is number.

- All left aligned, all inputType as number : it works
- All right aligned, all inputType as default(text): it works
- All right aligned, only the 1st one as number: it scrolls to the end
- All right aligned, all inputType as number: it scrolls to the end

The scrollview is scrolled to the left and keyboard is hidden, when I tap on the 1st editText the scrollview scrolls to the right, hidding the edittext currently focused

[image: Behavior]

EDIT : the problem occurs on device Nexus 7 (2012) 6.0.1 and emulator Nexus 7 5.1 and 4.4.2.  Its working fine on device Galaxy Tab3 4.4.2

if you want to try, this is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mainContentContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false">
            <TextView
                android:text="Test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:lines="1" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:hint="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="right" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:hint="2"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="right" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:hint="3"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="right" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:hint="4"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="right" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:hint="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="right" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this same problem. Interestingly the problem doesn't occur on android 7.

My solution/workaround (which is far from perfect) was to ditch the inputType and instead use a keylistener restricted to numbers.

In my case I was doing it in java and replaced this line

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

With this

```
setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789./-‌​"));
```

Which does what I'm after without the unexpected scrolling